# No implementation found for int io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetRealmPrivileges (long)

Tags: java, android, realm, proguard

I'm facing the the exception with realm db, application is crashing when it receives the following exception. Even I've updated the realm library and tried, but no luck.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetRealmPrivileges(long)(tried Java_io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm_nativeGetRealmPrivilegesand Java_io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm_nativeGetRealmPrivileges__J)

gradle:

```
release
{
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt') 
      proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'

 }
```

proGuard:

```
    realm

    -keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
    -keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
    -keep class io.realm.** { *; }
    -dontwarn javax.**
    -dontwarn io.realm.**

    realm 0.84.1+

    -keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
    -keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
    -keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
    -keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
    -dontwarn javax.**
    -dontwarn io.realm.**

    realm 0.89.0+

    -keep class io.realm.RealmCollection
    -keep class io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection
```

Comment: Are you using Sync platform? Do you have any dependencies that use Realm?

Comment: You might need to add `realm { syncEnabled true }` in your build.gradle